# What is the significance of Reclining Buddha Statue in Laos compared to other countries in Asia?

Tags: art, iconography, buddha, statue

Hello regarding the reclining Buddha statue here in this link http://www.buddhastatuesnow.com --

[image]

What are the differences between this and other reclining statues in Asia? I have seen several and this one is different. For example the fingers are much longer and the Buddha appears happy while in other countries he is more solemn and hands are not so prominent. Thank you for any info you can provide!

Comment: Hopefully someone who has good knowledge in Southeast Asia art reads your post.  For certain, I believe historical Buddha shaved his head.  It appears in many suttas that Buddha was called "bald headed monk" by people outside Buddhism to insult him.

Answer (score 1):

This is a depiction of the Buddha in his last moments of life, just before he achieved parinibbana (nirvana-after-death). There are 32 signs of a great man and 80 secondary signs (all of which the Buddha possessed) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_characteristics_of_the_Buddha#The_32_Signs_of_a_Great_Man and long slender fingers, long earlobes as depicted are two of the lesser signs.. I guess if you examine it up close, you will probably get some more  (foot arches etc?)! As for the differences, I am not well versed in art or its history, sorry!